# How to add subdomain for endpoint in Python EVE

Tags: python, eve

I am using Python Eve for creating different endpoints. I want to add subdomain to certain endpoint.

There is an way to create this through their custom endpoint feature like below

```py
agent_login = Blueprint("agentlogin", __name__, url_prefix="/agent", subdomain='<username>')
@agent_login.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def agentlogin(username):
    """ Code HERE """
    pass
```

Is there a way to achieve this in settings.py where we define DOMAIN?

```json
DOMAIN = {
     "index": {
        'item_title': 'index',
        'additional_lookup': {
            'url': 'regex("[\d]+")',
            'field': 'job_id'
        },
        'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
        'cache_expires': 10,

        # most global settings can be overridden at resource level
        'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],

        'schema': index_schema
    },
}
```

Comment: you want to add subdomains e.g. `users/login`, `users/forget_password` or what did you mean with endpoints?

Comment: something like "app.localhost:5000/index"

Comment: that can be easily done, I believe 
if you are using `Fastapi` you just set required URL and then add endpoints in the function decorator

Comment: I know that.! I want to achieve this with Python EVE framework..